# What is point density when using the random points processing algorithm?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm assuming the density of points means the number of points within an area. So if I use the settings shown in the image, the tool would make 1 point per 100 meters?

[image]

I tested this on a single polygon which is around 1,000 squared meters but the tool just hangs. After about 30 mins, I just quit it. Is my understanding correct? Should it take this long to generate a few points?

The project CRS is the same as the layer CRS (EPSG:27700).

Comment: It's impossible to pack 1000 points in a 1,000 squared meters polygon because minimum distance was set in 100 m (100 m x 100 m = 10,000 m2 = 1 ha; ten times higher than 1,000 squared meters). For this reason is comprehensible that tool just hangs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set a point density of 1 point for square meter. So, you'd have about 1000 points for a polygon about 1,000 squared meters. However, it's impossible to pack 1000 points in a 1,000 squared meters polygon because minimum distance was set in 100 m (100 m x 100 m = 10,000 m<sup>2</sup> = 1 ha; ten times higher than 1,000 squared meters). For this reason is comprehensible that tool just hangs. You should choose a considerably smaller minimum distance for this kind of polygons or choose 'Points count' as 'Sampling Strategy'.